# Figuring out all linked css/js when first starting on an existing site

Tags: javascript, html, css, coldfusion

I recently took on a website project that another developer left off. It's built using bootstrap and ColdFusion and I need to revise the visual components (turn dropdown into hover in nav, fix padding/margin, drop shadow around image etc...). I am having a hard time because there are so many css/js and other links in the the `<head>` already. It's hard to figure out what elements are controlled by what files.

Do you have any recommendation in the first steps when starting to work on an existing site? I am thinking maybe I should make a document to list out how all the css/js are connected to the html files before starting, but must I do this manually? Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use Firebug or Developer Tools in Chrome. When you inspect any element on website (just by right-click->inspect element) you can easily get information about files where particular rule for styling is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the Chrome developers tool, it's very powerful and doesn't just helps with the styling of the elements but also with js events. I recommend you to check out this video: http://vimeo.com/53073654 it helped me a lot.